# tcpdump doesn't captures properly on specific port

Tags: tcpdump

I'm in a network and i wanna capture ftp packets from another server in the network but i have a problem with tcpdump about this.

I've used this command :

```
tcpdump -i eth0 dst X.X.X.X -A and port 21
```

But it doesn't shows anything! ( i tested and sure that ftp port is 21 )

But if i use this on my server it works properly.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -A and port 21
```

I've this problem when i enter " port " in the command. but if i enter a command without specific port it works and captures properly.

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to ask a question, so this is part question and part insight.

Is the IP you're filtering on the client or the server for the FTP connection?

For the first command, try using src x.x.x.x or just host x.x.x.x and port 21.

For the second command, the "and" is not necessary with the -A flag.  This should look more like this:

```
tcpdump -A -i eth0 port 21
tcpdump -Ai eth0 port 21
```

Another thing I've seen is if there are vlan tags, normal filtering won't work without adding "vlan and " to your filter.  For example:

```
tcpdump -A -i eth0 "vlan and host x.x.x.x and port 21"
```

Also keep in mind that FTP uses a control and data connection.  The control is over port 21, but the data can vary depending on whether you're using active or passive FTP.

Comment: I don't think there is a reputation threshold for asking questions. You mean for commenting? Here you go...

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. My screen was scrolling by with ssh entries, but a `vlan and not port 22` did the trick.